# Django inlineformset_factory and ManyToMany fields

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm attempting to create a formset for the following models:

```
class Category(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(null = True, blank=True)

class Recipe(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, null = True, blank = True)
```

But any time I try to implement a formset, like so:

```
FormSet = inlineformset_factory(Category, Recipe, extra=3)
        formset = FormSet()
```

I get an error stating that no ForeignKey is present in the Category model. Is it possible to build a formset using a ManyToManyField, or to replicate this functionality in some way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to source code and documentation its only for foreign keys

So if you want create a formset for your models you have to change

```
categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, null = True, blank = True)
```

to

```
categories = models.ForeignKey("Category", null = True, blank = True)
```

Documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/#more-than-one-foreign-key-to-the-same-model

Django source:

```
def inlineformset_factory(parent_model, model, form=ModelForm,
                          formset=BaseInlineFormSet, fk_name=None,
                          fields=None, exclude=None,
                          extra=3, can_order=False, can_delete=True, max_num=None,
                          formfield_callback=None):
    """
    Returns an ``InlineFormSet`` for the given kwargs.

    You must provide ``fk_name`` if ``model`` has more than one ``ForeignKey``
    to ``parent_model``.
    """
```

Comment: Yeah, looks like you're right. I'm trying to get around this by creating custom fields with my own init and save methods.

Comment: @bento, I know this is kind off old, but did you get to do the workaround? I'm in the same situation as you and would like to know how you resolved it.

Comment: I have long since using Django, unfortunately, and I can't really remember what I ended up doing. Sorry!