# Django: Prepopulate extra fields in a Formset with a ManyToMany Model

Tags: django, many-to-many, formset

I have two models with a ManyToMany (M2M) relationship. In order to have extra fields on the M2M Model, I defined a `through=` model. I tried setting up a inlineformset_factory, using `parent=ChildModel` and `model=ParentModel.parent_child.through` as described in this thread [pendant to inline formsets for many-to-many relations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22238690/pendant-to-inline-formsets-for-many-to-many-relations). But it did not solve my issue.

How can I access (i.e. prepopulate) and update the extra fields of the M2M model, when using formsets?

**models.py**

```
class ParentModel(models.Model):
    name = model.CharField()
    parent_child = model.ManyToManyField(ChildModel, through='ParentChildModel')


class ChildModel(models.Model):
    name = model.CharField()
    

class ParentChildModel(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(ParentModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    child = models.ForeignKey(ChildModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    extra_field_1 = models.CharField()
```

**forms.py**

```
class ChildForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = ChildModel
        fields = '__all__'



ChildFormset = modelformset_factory(ChildModel,
                                     form=ChildForm,
                                     extra=0,
                                     can_delete=True,
                                     can_order=True,
                                     )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, setting up a `ModelFormset` on the `ChildModel`. For the extra field of the `ParentChildModel`, I defined a field in `form.py` which I manually populate using the code down below.

**views.py**

```
# get instances
parent_instance = Parent.objects.get(id=pk)
parent_children = parent_instance.parent_child.all()
parent_child_instance = ParentChildModel.objects.filter(parent=parent_instance)

# initializing & prepopulate forms
parent_form = ParentForm(request.POST or None, instance=parent_instance)
child_formset = ChildFormset(request.POST or None, queryset=parent_children)
for child_form in child_formset:
    child_form.fields['extra_field_1'].initial = parent_child_instance.get(child=child_form.instance).extra_field_1
```

**forms.py**

```
class ChildForm(forms.ModelForm):
    extra_field_1 = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = ChildModel
        fields = '__all__'


ChildFormset = modelformset_factory(ChildModel,
                                    form=ChildForm,
                                    ...
                                    )
```

Answer (score -1):

You would need to create a formset with the `ParentChildModel` and an instance of `ChildModel` instead of just using the `ChildModel` as it won't be able to access `extra_field_1`.

The documentation suggests an inline-formset structure like this:

```py
from django.forms import inlineformset_factory

ParentChildFormset = inlineformset_factory(ChildModel, ParentChildModel, ...)
child = ChildModel.objects.get(...)
formset = ParentChildFormset(instance=child)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets

Comment: @OsVoid If you pass in a ChildModel instance in the Formset, that you are missing the FK of the ParentModel to get the right instances in the ParentChildModel. My logic would suggest that I need a Formset based on the ParentChildModel and pass in the respective instances. But like this, I struggle with getting the Data from the ParentModel and ChildModel.